# Using the 'str.join' syntax within the robot framework

Tags: python, join, robotframework

I was looking to implement the Python `str.join` function on the robot framework level and I'm not sure of the proper syntax. I've also showed what the code looks like in Python (which works)

I've tried this:

Robot:

```
Set Suite Variable  @{list} ['a', 'h', 'b', 'a', 'f', 'h', 'l']
Log @{','.join(list)}
```

Code in Python:

```
P = ['a', 'h', 'b', 'a', 'f', 'h', 'l']
print ','.join(P)
```

Answer (score 5):

Use BuiltIn's [Catenate](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Catenate).

`${my string}=    Catenate    SEPARATOR=,    @{list}`

Also, you are not creating a list in your question. It should look more like this:

`@{list}=    Create List    a    h    b    a    f    h    l`